# adapted, increasing, (locally) integrable variation process is a (local) submartingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, conditional-probability, stochastic-analysis

I read a theorem that an adapted, increasing, (locally) integrable integrable, variation process is a (local) submartingale. (here increasing includes right continuity).

Definition: A process is $\textbf{increasing}$ if each sample path is increasing and right continuous

Definition: A process has $\textbf{finite variation}$ if it is the difference of two increasing processes

Definition: Let $X$ be a process with finite variation. We define the variation process $V_X$ by setting $V_X(t,\omega)$ to be the variation of $X(\cdot, \omega)$ on $[0,t]$

Definition: A process is said to be $\textbf{integrable}$ if $\sup_{t\geq 0 } \mathbb{E}|X_t|<\infty$

Note: For an increasing, nonnegative process $X$ is integrable is equivalent to $X_{\infty}$ existing a.s. and being an integrable random variable.

Definition: A finite variation process $X$ is said to have $\textbf{integrable variation}$ if $V_X$ is integrable.

Definiton: A finite variation process $X$ is said to have $\textbf{locally integrable variation}$ if there exists a sequence of stopping times $(T_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $T_n \nearrow \infty$ a.s. and for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $X^{T_n}$ has integrable variation

Put $A$ to be our increasing process with locally integrable variation. So I know the adapted condition is satisfied, as is the increasing conditional expectation condition. But I cannot see how locally integrable variation implies for each $t \geq 0$, $\mathbb{E}|A_t| < \infty$. The proof in the book (Klebner) is short but mentions (regardless of integrable or locally integrable variation) that it has to do with the localizing sequence. Since I'm new to localized properties, could someone explain?

From assumption, we can choose our localizing sequence $(T_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $T_n \nearrow \infty$ a.s. and for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\sup_{t \geq 0} \mathbb{E} [{V_A}_{t \wedge T_n}] < \infty$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by locally integrable variation? Could you add the definition?

Comment: Oh yeah, I'll edit that in

Comment: You added a lot of definitions, but as far as I can see you didn't define "locally integrable variation"? Do you define "locally integrable" via a localizing sequence of stopping times?

Comment: exactly, I'll add that in too

Comment: Well, if the variation process is integrable, then the assertion is a direct consequence of the fact that $$|X_t-X_0| \leq V_X(t).$$ (Actually, they are equal because of the monotonicity of the sample paths.) However, I currently don't see why the assertion should be true if the variation process is only locally integrable.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, I misread what was going on. The whole point of this was to define the compensator of a finite variation process with (locally) integrable variation. The proof is in Klebner pg 228 and I just misunderstood what was going on. He uses the doob meyer decomposition which applies to local submartingales as well, and so it suffices to get a local submartingale in my question. So I'll change the problem for future readers.

Comment: Thanks for your help and discussion.